# Find most common path in directed cyclic graph

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to find the top ten most travelled paths for a cyclic graph that go from start to contact or start to not contact. I have weights for each branch. I can probably brute force this there are a couple of thousand nodes in my data set, but is there an algorithm to do this? My data looks like [(a, b, 2), (c, d, 1)... ]. There are a couple of thousand nodes.

[image]

Comment: How many data sets of recorded travels do you have? In which format do you have them?

Comment: I would not describe the shown graph as "cyclic". On the contrary, it seems that any node, once left, cannot be reached again. I'd call that non-cyclic.

Comment: Sorry the diagram is not accurate, I will update it. I have a couple of thousands nodes. They are in the format of [(a, b, 2), (b, c, 3) ... ]

Comment: When you talk about "most common path," do you have some sort of probability distribution over how users walk from one page to the next? Is it uniformly-random?

Comment: Yes I have counts for how many users go from one page to another.